# Node-sass includePaths in command line?

Tags: node.js, sass, browserify, bourbon, node-sass

So I'm setting up a new project, and I want to use Bourbon for scss via npm. This requires doing `npm install bourbon`, and then somehow piping the path into node-sass at time of compilation.

My current sass script looks like this:

```
node-sass --output-style compressed -o build/css/ scss/
```

And the [Bourbon docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon) indicate that I need to do something like:

```
require("bourbon").includePaths
```

But how do I do this via the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add bourbon stylesheets with the `include-path` option in the command line like this (multiline for readability, needs to be on single line in `package.json`):

```
node-sass 
--include-path node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/  
--output-style compressed -o build/css/ scss/
```